# Why is my text not showing in my textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea where I change some text and insert it with some javascript code, but it isn't showing up. I can see it through firebug, that it's there but on the screen I can't see anything. Any ideas?

*Yeah, I don't think it's a problem in my js-code. It can be with some styling issues or something.*

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="ta_eftertext" id="ta_eftertext">Bajskorv Aftertext hello world! </textarea>
```

[JSfiddle example!!!](http://jsfiddle.net/gWXxd/1/)

Comment: To change the contents of a `<textarea>` you should set its "value" property. With jQuery that'd be `$('#ta_eftertext').val("hello world");`

Comment: Ok, I'm actually using .text().

Comment: .text() should work, too. Please make a jsfiddle

Comment: shows up fine here http://jsfiddle.net/kvBj8/1/

Comment: Please include the javascript you're using to insert the text

Comment: Wow `.text()`, `.html()`, and `.val()` all work :-)

Comment: Just use .val(). It's the most consistent and correct.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is erroneous - it gets an error because you never declared the variable "fortext".  If you change that to a string, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

html:

```
<textarea id="textArea">
</textarea>​
```

and js:

```
$('#textArea').val('text');
```

Comment: How is that different from his example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery .text like this:

```
$('#ta_eftertext').text("foo");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kannix/ZEjN7/